# how to get the fully qualified name of a method call when it exists in the source code using javaparser

Tags: javaparser

My test code to excercise various functions of JavaParser:

public class test001 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test001 t = new test001();
    t.run();
    }

@sample.mkGetSet
int g1;

@sample.start
test001(){
    g1 = 14;
    }

@sample.funky
void run() {
    @sample.flagVar
    int a,b,c;
    
    a=1;
    b=2;
    c=a+b;
    c=c+g1;
    System.out.println("result:"+c);
    }
}
```

My code correctly notes that I call println in the method run.
Is there a fairly easy way to get the 'System.out.' part in addition to the println part?
In the case where the qualification is not there, I dont need it but if it is i would like it.
The type of answer I'm looking for is along the line of 'In the MethodCallExpr look at XXXXX' (with the obligatory admonition to RTFD)
I've been over the documentation and its still not clear how to do this - or if i even can.